# Windows Explorer Thumbs Folder

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, usb-flash-drive

I support an application that creates several folders, which the users copy to portable SSDs at the end of each session. The folder structure contains directories called "Photos","Orders" and .. "Thumbs". Note this isn't a file called "Thumbs.db" which is the source of a lot of queries about file copying, just a folder called "Thumbs" in which are stored image thumbnails.

I get regular calls from users who complain that when copying their working folder structure to external disk, everything is present but the Thumbs folder is completely missing. All the other files are there. This occurs for different users a couple of times a week but many other users are unaffected.

My question is whether there is a known issue with Windows being sensitive particularly to folders called Thumbs, perhaps not copying it because of some arcane rule about not copying Thumbs* folders and files related to the Thumbnail Database file. Its a long shot, but someone else might have seen this.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no issue like that.

A folder named "Thumbs" is not a file named "Thumbs.db". ;)

You need to get the user to show you what happens, and then keep an eye out for error messages, hidden folders, files in the folder being held open in running programs, user error, etc.

Comment: Nope, I've never heard of that issue either, as I said, a long shot. Thanks for your response. I'll just let the issue hang for a couple of days to see if there are any other replies before I upvote your answer.